# Automatically taking money from my Credit card monthly

Tags: credit, automation

I Live in the UK and am looking for a way to automatically take a certain amount from my Credit Card monthly.

The first thing that came to my mind was Direct Debit, however it seems Direct Debit is not possible with Credit cards as they do not have a Account number and Sort Code.

How can I achieve a similar result? I do not want to have to remember to spend or withdraw a certain amount each month(must be automated)

Comment: Are you paying a bill each month or taking cash out of the CC each month? Because if you are taking cash out each month there is no interest free period. If you are paying a bill you can set up automatic credit card payments with the service provider issuing the bill.

Comment: @MarkDoony I am actually paying nothing, I just want to move money from this credit card so it looks like I am using it.

Comment: @JimbuBaggerman: If you are not paying for anything, you will have to pay interest for the money you withdraw. On the other hand, you may set up an automatic payment to a charity of your choice (and maybe even get some tax benefits from that).

Comment: Are you talking about taking a cash advance from your credit card each month? When would you pay it back? What is the purpose of your cash advances?

Comment: Don't you have any monthly bills like telephone, etc. which you can set up atuo payments with your credit card. This way you still qualify for the interest free period.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling money out of a credit card is generally a bad idea.  You'll be hit with interest from day 1, and some credit cards have cash advance fees on top of that.

If you are really desperate for running up an automatic charge on your credit card to maintain use, then you have a few options:

- Auto-pay an existing bill.  For example, utility bills, loan payments (if that's an option), etc.
- Create a new bill.  For example, donate to a charity, church, or other non-profit.

Personally, the charity route makes the most sense to me.  You can probably set up an automatic donation of less than 5 quid, and it may be tax deductible to boot.  Plus, you're helping an organization that (hopefully) is doing some good in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that a credit card does have an account number and sort code, I have had a Visa card previously and currently have a Mastercard. Both were paid by Direct Debit, and I could then transfer money to the account when I wanted to pay more than the minimum payment off.

Check the introductory letter from the card provider, it should be on there, failing that, contact the provider and ask them for the details, how to pay, or a direct debit mandate for either the whole amount or the minimum amount.